# What can trigger postgresql shutdown?

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

Today on one of my servers strange thing happened: postgresql turned off by itself.

I checked postrgesql logs (`/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`) and this is what I found:

> 2017-08-16 07:56:18 CEST [1601-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
> 2017-08-16 07:56:18 CEST [1601-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
> 2017-08-16 07:56:18 CEST [1606-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
> 2017-08-16 07:56:18 CEST [1603-1] LOG:  shutting down
> 2017-08-16 07:56:18 CEST [1603-2] LOG:  database system is shut down

Previous entries are from June, so they are irrelevant.

Nobody logged in to the machine for almost two weeks (according to the logs...).

Assuming that I'm not hacked what could trigger this shutdown request? What can I do to find out what happened?

I had to turn on postgres again because it's production machine, but I really want to know what had happened.

I have PostgreSQL 9.5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar post on Database Administrators with an answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14199/postgresql-performed-a-fast-shutdown-by-itself-why-how-was-it-able-to-do-tha

Maybe this will help?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, Now I need to find out why this package was upgraded, even though it shouldn't ;)